# Swing/JavaFx Hybrid Application with crashing TextField

Tags: swing, javafx

I have a problem which is affecting an application that for various reasons had to be written using Swing JFrames containing JavaFx panels. I can reduce the code to a simple example, based on code from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm.

My example opens an application containing a button that can open a simple dialog which has a textfield. If I type into the dialog's textfield, everything is fine, but if I start typing then click on anything outside the dialog (e.g. a text editor), when i go back to the textfield and type some more if behaves oddly and starts throwing exceptions. This appears to be where something is not happening on the EDT or Application thread, and I'm quite sure it's down the the dialog's show() method, though I can't see what is wrong. As far as i can tell, i've followed the correct pattern.

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_171 and IntelliJ Idea on Windows 10.

The code is as follows:

Application:

```
public class HybridApplication
{
    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> initAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(() -> initFX(fxPanel));
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(20);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
        TextField text = new TextField();

        text.setPrefWidth(200);
        text.setPrefHeight(40);

        HybridDialog dialog = new HybridDialog();

        Button button = new Button("Test");

        button.setOnAction(event -> dialog.show());

        hBox.getChildren().add(button);
        hBox.getChildren().add(text);

        return scene;
    }
}
```

---

Dialog:

```
public class HybridDialog
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public HybridDialog()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> initAndShowGUI());
    }

    private void initAndShowGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Dialog");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(() -> initFX(fxPanel));
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        TextField text = new TextField();

        text.setPrefWidth(200);
        text.setPrefHeight(40);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().add(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);

        return scene;
    }

    public void show() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

---

The odd behaviour is that when i resume typing, say to edit what i'd typed, the textfield starts adding chunks of the text after the cursor and I soon get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1273)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getYRendering(Text.java:1069)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$4400(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$TextAttribute$11.computeValue(Text.java:1785)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$TextAttribute$11.computeValue(Text.java:1777)
    at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.get(ObjectBinding.java:153)
    at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.get(ObjectPropertyBase.java:132)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.lambda$new$198(TextFieldSkin.java:233)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.access$000(ObjectPropertyBase.java:51)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(ObjectPropertyBase.java:233)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.invalidate(ObjectBinding.java:172)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_geomChanged(Text.java:769)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsTextLayout(Text.java:194)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:189)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$2.invalidated(Text.java:389)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.access$000(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(StringPropertyBase.java:230)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding.invalidate(StringBinding.java:171)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.BindingHelperObserver.invalidated(BindingHelperObserver.java:51)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.fireValueChangedEvent(TextInputControl.java:1389)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.markInvalid(TextInputControl.java:1393)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.controlContentHasChanged(TextInputControl.java:1332)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.access$1600(TextInputControl.java:1300)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.lambda$new$162(TextInputControl.java:139)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextField$TextFieldContent.insert(TextField.java:87)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:1204)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:556)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin.replaceText(TextFieldSkin.java:576)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.replaceText(TextFieldBehavior.java:202)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.defaultKeyTyped(TextInputControlBehavior.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:139)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene.lambda$null$299(EmbeddedScene.java:310)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene.lambda$keyEvent$300(EmbeddedScene.java:296)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If i keep typing, the following line appears in the IDE as if locked in a loop:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Thanks, in advance, for any help anyone can give.